# How do I concatenate cell entries in a struct?

Tags: matlab

I have a structure, say, S

S = 1XM structure

S has 2 fields, S.Car and S.Bike.

S(i).Car = NX1 cell structure, where i can be any value.

How do I concatenate all M entries into a giant cell array? That is, I am looking for something similar to this:

```
Ans = [S(:).Car]
```

Except here, it doesn't work because it throws the following error:

> Error using horzcat
>   Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

This makes sense because it is attempting a horizontal concatenation of the entries when clearly they have different row sizes. However, this doesn't work either:

```
Ans = [S(:).Car']
```

> Error using  ' 
>   Too many input arguments.

How do I do this without calling any special function?

Answer (score 0):

Convert from structure to cell first, then unpack the cell.

```
s(1).car = {1,'a'};
s(2).car  = {'b',{'c'},3};

a = {s(:).car};
b = [a{:}].'
```